# How to Connect to WiFi 802.1x with QR Code

Tags: wifi, qr-code

I'm traying to get a QR code for connecting android an IOS devices to a WPA2-EAP netowork,

this is what i'm traying but does nothing
`WIFI:T:WPA2-EAP;S:[NETOWORK NAME];E:PEAP;PH2:None;A:anon;I:test;P:123test;;`

I need the A: [anonymous identity] to be set to "Do not validate"   and PH2:[Phase 2 method] to None.

There is not much information around. any ideas how to proceed?